# How to turn on dns query over tcp under Alpine Linux 3.18

Tags: alpine-linux

In Alpine Linux 3.18.0 release notes page. [Release_Notes_for_Alpine_3.18.0](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Release_Notes_for_Alpine_3.18.0)

> musl 1.2.4 Support for DNS lookups over TCP.

But there is no more information about how to turn it.
Then i modified the /etc/resolv.conf file, append use-vc option to options, like the following:

```
options timeout:2 attempts:3 rotate single-request-reopen use-vc
; generated by /usr/sbin/dhclient-script
nameserver 100.100.2.136
nameserver 100.100.2.138
```

or

```
options timeout:2 attempts:3 rotate single-request-reopen tcp
; generated by /usr/sbin/dhclient-script
nameserver 100.100.2.136
nameserver 100.100.2.138
```

and ran the following c program demo:

```
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <netdb.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
struct addrinfo hints;
struct addrinfo *result, *rp;
int s;
char host[256];

if (argc != 2){
    printf("An argument must be specified, Usage:\n./%s <domainname or hostname>\n", argv[1]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = 0;

s = getaddrinfo(argv[1], NULL, &hints, &result);
if (s != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {
    getnameinfo(rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen, host, sizeof(host), NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);
    printf("%s\n", host);
}
freeaddrinfo(result);
```

}

```bash
./getaddrinfo-demo stackoverflow.com
151.101.1.69
151.101.65.69
151.101.129.69
151.101.193.69
```

Run the tcpdump command ahead of time in another window.

```bash
tcpdump -i eth0 -s 0 -nnv
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
20:09:26.732572 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 47125, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 63)
    172.17.0.3.46864 > 100.100.2.136.53: 53899+ A? stackoverflow.com. (35)
20:09:26.732604 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16021, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 63)
    172.17.0.3.46864 > 100.100.2.138.53: 53899+ A? stackoverflow.com. (35)
20:09:26.732839 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 62, id 47125, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 127)
    100.100.2.136.53 > 172.17.0.3.46864: 53899 4/0/0 stackoverflow.com. A 151.101.1.69, stackoverflow.com. A 151.101.129.69, stackoverflow.com. A 151.101.65.69, stackoverflow.com. A 151.101.193.69 (99)
20:09:26.732841 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 62, id 16021, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 127)
    100.100.2.138.53 > 172.17.0.3.46864: 53899 4/0/0 stackoverflow.com. A 151.101.65.69, stackoverflow.com. A 151.101.193.69, stackoverflow.com. A 151.101.1.69, stackoverflow.com. A 151.101.129.69 (99)
```

but it use udp still.

So, how to turn on dns query over tcp under Alpine Linux 3.18 ?

Comment: did you find a way to turn the dns using tcp?

Comment: Yes, When the returned data is larger than 1024 bytes, it will be automatically converted from udp to tcp, no need to open it manually.

Comment: yes, I found it in the alpine official. from 3.18, support auto switch when greater thatn 512 Byte.